# Improve performance of ST_Extent query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to make my own vector tiles and I am using Mapbox Studio Classic for that purpose.
When I export my dataset, Mapbox Studio will try to figure out the extend of my data and those queries take very long.

The query it's performing is like this:

```
SELECT 
  ST_XMin(ext),
  ST_YMin(ext),
  ST_XMax(ext),
  ST_YMax(ext)
FROM (SELECT ST_Extent(geom) as ext from cont) as tmp`
```

And my cont table is quite huge with a lot of short (non of them is long) contour lines in it.
It has an index on the geom column (GIST).

The query is taking a LOT of time (several minutes) on our beefed up machine.

Is there a way to improve the performance of that query?

EDIT:

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` generates:

```
Subquery Scan on tmp  (cost=13016236.00..13016236.04 rows=1 width=65) (actual time=2245959.393..2245959.396 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=39596394 read=21929928
  ->  Aggregate  (cost=13016236.00..13016236.01 rows=1 width=5190) (actual time=2245952.748..2245952.748 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=39596394 read=21929928
        ->  Seq Scan on cont  (cost=0.00..12830974.00 rows=74104800 width=5190) (actual time=0.014..104310.564 rows=74119236 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=3343020 read=8746906
Planning time: 0.086 ms
Execution time: 2245959.495 ms
```

Comment: What is the output of [`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions)

Comment: Suggest Mapbox to add https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EstimatedExtent.html as an alternative. User must keep the statistics up to date.

Comment: @jgh see my edited question for the explain (analyze, buffers)

Comment: `ST_Extent` does not use the geometry index. It evaluates the full geometries, thus it takes a while as it scans thru each geometry in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ST_Extent` is slow because it "does not read the serialized cached bounding box (since that is floating point) but calculates the box in full from the underlying geometry." (from [postgis/lwgeom_box3d.c](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/aa09c3eaf1c47a8debd08a54f1e8bed2c1346be0/postgis/lwgeom_box3d.c#L450-L456)).

If you need an approximate extent that is 95% close, use [`ST_EstimatedExtent`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EstimatedExtent.html).

If the table is brand-new or has been significantly altered, update the statistics:

```
VACUUM ANALYZE cont;
```

Then get an approximate `box2d` result:

```
SELECT ST_EstimatedExtent('cont', 'geom');
```

Comment: Wow... `ST_EstimatedExtent` is blazing fast...
I worked around the problem by using a command-line tool that does not ask for the extent... but that would for sure improve the export speed a lot... but as Mapbox Studio Classic is no longer maintained, I guess they won't change it...
Anyway... thanks a lot!!!